# C# vsto Powerpoint pastespecial fails when using ppPasteMetafilePicture

Tags: c#, types, powerpoint, vsto, paste

I'm trying to paste metapicture from clipboard (from excel) into a powerpoint slide using the code part below. It works fine when I use ppPasteDefault or ppPasteBitmap paste types but fails when using ppPasteMetafilePicture or prety much anything else.

I receive  error; "Shapes (unknown member) : Invalid request.  The specified data type is unavailable."

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(Clipboard.GetImage());

s.Application.Activate();

var p = s.Shapes.PasteSpecial(Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpPasteDataType.ppPasteDefault, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, "", 0, "", Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse);
```

Comment: It's a common problem; apparently there's a timing issue. The paste operation is called before Windows has finished putting needed data on the clipboard.  In VBA, you'd do the paste within a loop that repeatedly tests p to see if it's = Nothing and continue once it becomes "non-nothing".

Comment: well, I read about that, but I don't think it's the issue. Even if I add 10 sec. wait before paste (Thread.Sleep(10000);) still I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason after investigating for hours.
It seems what I copied into clipboard should be enhancedmetapicture instead of a bitmap.
So I changed my range copying excel part picture type from xlBitmap to xlPicture and then it worked.